# How to disable error logs for users' home directories in Apache?

Tags: logging, apache-http-server

I cannot figure out how to disable error logging for Apache. I've found a few manuals for access logs and they work perfect.

Is it possible to disable error logging for some directories? I specifically want to disable error logs for users' home directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /home>
  LogLevel emerg
</Directory>
```

Should work fine enough. (Reduces `ErrorLog` to "emergency" level, which is "web server is on fire, please call 911" seldom.)

If you're weird and use `/home/www` for the `DocumentRoot`, you'll need

```
 <LocationMatch /~([^/]*)/>
```

or similar, depending on how you use `mod_userdir`.

Comment: Thx, but LogLevel directive is not allowed on directory [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#loglevel)

Comment: It is in Apache 2.4: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#loglevel